# No me deja conectarme a mysql usando mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

El código es el siguiente:

```
$logID = checkParam($_GET["id"]);
$database = mysqli_connect($config["db_server"], $config["db_user"], $config["db_password"], $config["db_name"]);

if($database)
{
    if($logID != null)
    {
        $log = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE `id`='$logID';")->fetch_array();

        if($log["id"] != null)
        {
            $fpath = "./server/". $config["logs_folder"]."/". $bot["user"]."".$bot["hwid"].".zip";
            unlink($fpath);

            $database->query("DELETE FROM `logs` WHERE `id`='$logID'");
        }

        header('Location: http://'. $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] .'/index');
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Can't connect to MySQL";
    exit(0);
}
```

Pero cuando lo hago me arroja el siguiente error:

> Can't connect to MySQL

Que debo hacer? lo cambio todo a POO o porque no me conecta con mysqli?

Comment: Ese error suele tener una causa a continuación. Podrías mostrar el mensaje de error completo?

Comment: a que te refieres con causa?  la causa es que cuando presiono el boton intento conectarme a la base de datos, pero no conecta. el mensaje es el que cite.

Comment: Con "causa" me refiero a que suele traer un código de error o algo similar; ej: `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`. Con el fragmento del mensaje de error que muestras, las causas pueden ser muchas y es difícil responderte de forma adecuada.

Comment: Deberías mostrar dónde defines las variables $config o puedes hacer un var_dump de las mismas a ver que valor tienen. Puede que el error sea tan simple como que no están definidas y sin ver esa parte del código, lo único que puedo decirte es que si llega a la parte else es porque $database es false.

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que el servidor de MySQL no esté escuchando donde intentas o algún otro parametro no sea correcto.

Por ejemplo el servidor solo escucha en local (localhost y/o 127.0.0.1) y estás accediendo desde otra maquina. También puede ser que intentes acceder por IP y solo acepte conexiones sock. O que el puerto no sea el mismo en el que el servidor está escuchando. También puede ser que el usuario ó clave no sea correcto. O que el usuario solo este asociado a un host concreto y no sea accesible.

Existe una lista completa de posibles problemas de conexión en MySQL.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Pero al no tener el error real que aparece es difícil conocer qué pasa realmente. Puedes usar las funciones de error de MySQLi en php para obtener el código y mensaje de error:

`mysqli_connect_errno();` y `mysqli_connect_error();`

Con esta información será mas sencillo saber que esta pasando y actuar en consecuencia.

Answer (score 0):

Declara tu conexion en otro archivo: `conexion.php`

```
<?php

  DEFINE ('DB_USUARIO','user');
  DEFINE ('DB_CLAVE','pass');
  DEFINE ('DB_HOST','localhost');
  DEFINE ('DB_NOMBRE','database');
   $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USUARIO,DB_CLAVE,DB_NOMBRE);
   mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
 ?>
```

Y de donde vallas a utilizarlo en tus archivo de consulta etc. Archivo `consulta.php`

```
include('conexion.php');
```

Para realizar las operaciones las haces de la siguiente forma:

```
$result  = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM tabla') or mysqli_error($con);
```